# FileMaker Pro 14 Calculating Pie Graph Axes

Tags: sql, database, filemaker

So let's say I have a table called Work Table:

```
Name    Program Hours
John    FDA     3
Jacob   FDA     4
John    FDA     2
John    AHA     1
Jacob   AHA     5
Jacob   AHA     7
Jacob   FDA     8
John    AHA     12
```

If I were to graph this in a pie chart, it would show each record on the pie chart. The legend would have two spots for FDA and two spots for AHA rather adding them up together. I need them to add up together so that it displays the total hours attributed to FDA for each person in one pie slice, and the total hours attributed to AHA for each person. The "each person" part I have down already with a subsummary part in my layout, but not adding up the third column values when they match in the second column.

I've tried running an ExecuteSQL calculation in each of the fields. For some reason when I try to post them here I get an error and stackoverflow won't let me post the question, so here is an image of the SQL I'm using:

[image]

So far, this is not working properly. The best I can say is that the slice data appears to be putting each item to the same number, because the pie chart is divided equally among its parts. I'm getting nothing but a question mark for the labels.

Any suggestions on how to fix this query OR another approach to satisfy my goal would be most appreciated.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your requirement. In your example, there are two persons and two programs. How many pie charts do you want to show, with how many slices (each)?

Comment: I have a subsummary already that gives me the two pie charts, one for John and one for Jacob. The problem is, each individual pie chart has four slices. On each pie chart, two of those slices are called FDA, the other two are called AHA. On John's chart for example, rather than have a FDA slice of 3 and an FDA slice of 2, it should have one FDA slice that says 5. John's AHA slice should say 13 rather than two slices of 1 and 12 respectively. Does that make sense?

Comment: So would this be the result you're looking for? http://i.stack.imgur.com/bW79O.png

Comment: Yes, that is indeed the result I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using a native Filemaker approach.

In addition to the existing fields, you need to define a summary field `sTotal` as Total of Hours.

The reporting layout needs to have a sub-summary part when sorted by `Name`. Place your chart in this part.

Define the chart as follows:

[image]

To display the chart, you need to sort the records by (1) `Name` and by (2) `Program`. To have the larger slices appear first, set the `Program` field's sort order to descending + Reorder based on summary field `sTotal`.

Comment: Yes, thank you. This worked exactly how I wanted it to.